# Select an image within a column with CSS

Tags: css

Hi first question here.

I need to select an image within a column within a section to modify its positioning and move it to the left about 150px.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShY66.jpg)

Normally according to the image/code attached I'd do:

```
#_42y9tqw50 .kartra_image
{
position: relative;
left:150px;
}
```

That's not working. Any suggestions?

```html
<div class="content" style="padding: 70px 0px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" id="_42y9tqw50">
                <div class="background_changer background_changer--blur0" alt="" style="background-image: none; opacity: 1;" data-was-processed="true"></div>
                <div class="background_changer_overlay" style="background-image: none;"></div>
                <div class="container"><div class="row" data-component="grid">
<div class="col-md-4 colView"><div class="js_kartra_component_holder">
<div data-component="headline" id="UfRz5JnRus">
                            <div class="kartra_headline kartra_headline--dim-black kartra_headline--size-giant kartra_headline--open-sans-font kartra_headline--font-weight-bold kartra_headline--text-center" style="position: relative;">
<p style="font-family: Lato;">Healthy Nutrition Just Got Easier</p>
</div>
                        </div>
<div data-component="text" id="UWS7hfIw3U">
                            <div class="kartra_text kartra_text--light-grey kartra_text--text-medium kartra_text--text-center kartra_text--margin-bottom-medium" style="position: relative;">
<p style="font-family: Lato;">Healthy and Yummy Immunity Boosting recipes pack to strengthen your immune system, eat healthy and keep the weight you deserve.</p>
</div>
                        </div>
</div></div>
<div class="col-md-8 colView"><div class="js_kartra_component_holder"><div data-component="image" href="javascript: void(0);"><picture><source type="image/webp" data-srcset="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.webp" srcset="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.webp"><source type="image/png" data-srcset="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.png" srcset="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.png"><img class="kartra_image kartra_image--full pull-left background_changer--blur0 loaded" src="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.png" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='//d2uolguxr56s4e.cloudfront.net/img/kartrapages/placeholder.jpg';" alt="" style="border-color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-style: none; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; opacity: 1;" data-original="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.png" data-was-processed="true"></picture></div></div></div>
</div></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: If you want to move it to the left then shouldn't you use left:-150px;  maybe your code is already fine. Unless i misunderstood the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe give this a try.

```
.col-md-8 > .js_kartra_component_holder >div > picture > img.kartra_image{
transform: translateX(-150px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply John! 

.kartra_image though selects and moves all images within the page.
I would need to select only the image within that section.

Comment: @LorenzoGiaccardi I have updated my answer. Please take a look and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @John This is bad style really. You use too many selectors. The processor has to start at the kartra_image and propagate all the way up to ensure the chain of selectors is accurate. Why not just use a class or a ID instead? Much better.

Comment: @F.Müller Yes adding a class or ID would be the best way to achieve this, but the OP asked how to do it with CSS.  It is not known if he can change his current HTML code.

Comment: @John Alright. But its not bad to point that out in the answer. It will help others readers and improve your answer, too

Comment: @John thank you. It worked out. Thanks a lot! Especially the translateX command didn't find it elsewhere. Very useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can set left to a negative value. Or you may use the css-transform property as already pointed out by @John.

Besides, you can just use `position: absolute` instead of `position: relative` if you don't plan to adjust any child-elements of the div. Because this will just set the reference point for absolute positioning.

```css
#_42y9tqw50 .kartra_image {
  position: absolute;
  left: -150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" style="padding: 70px 0px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" id="_42y9tqw50">
  <div class="background_changer background_changer--blur0" alt="" style="background-image: none; opacity: 1;" data-was-processed="true"></div>
  <div class="background_changer_overlay" style="background-image: none;"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" data-component="grid">
      <div class="col-md-4 colView">
        <div class="js_kartra_component_holder">
          <div data-component="headline" id="UfRz5JnRus">
            <div class="kartra_headline kartra_headline--dim-black kartra_headline--size-giant kartra_headline--open-sans-font kartra_headline--font-weight-bold kartra_headline--text-center" style="position: relative;">
              <p style="font-family: Lato;">Healthy Nutrition Just Got Easier</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div data-component="text" id="UWS7hfIw3U">
            <div class="kartra_text kartra_text--light-grey kartra_text--text-medium kartra_text--text-center kartra_text--margin-bottom-medium" style="position: relative;">
              <p style="font-family: Lato;">Healthy and Yummy Immunity Boosting recipes pack to strengthen your immune system, eat healthy and keep the weight you deserve.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 colView">
        <div class="js_kartra_component_holder">
          <div data-component="image" href="javascript: void(0);">
            <picture>
              <source type="image/webp" data-srcset="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.webp" srcset="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.webp">
              <source type="image/png" data-srcset="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.png" srcset="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.png"><img class="kartra_image kartra_image--full pull-left background_changer--blur0 loaded" src="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.png" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='//d2uolguxr56s4e.cloudfront.net/img/kartrapages/placeholder.jpg';"
                alt="" style="border-color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-style: none; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; opacity: 1;" data-original="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.png" data-was-processed="true"></picture>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have my upvote kind stranger. 
Problem solved 

Comment: @LorenzoGiaccardi No problem. I did not receive an upvote though (if this was intended). Did you mark the wrong answer by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

To move it "to the left" use left:-150px; instead of left:150px;

```css
#_42y9tqw50 .kartra_image {
  position: relative;
  left: -150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" style="padding: 70px 0px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" id="_42y9tqw50">
  <div class="background_changer background_changer--blur0" alt="" style="background-image: none; opacity: 1;" data-was-processed="true"></div>
  <div class="background_changer_overlay" style="background-image: none;"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" data-component="grid">
      <div class="col-md-4 colView">
        <div class="js_kartra_component_holder">
          <div data-component="headline" id="UfRz5JnRus">
            <div class="kartra_headline kartra_headline--dim-black kartra_headline--size-giant kartra_headline--open-sans-font kartra_headline--font-weight-bold kartra_headline--text-center" style="position: relative;">
              <p style="font-family: Lato;">Healthy Nutrition Just Got Easier</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div data-component="text" id="UWS7hfIw3U">
            <div class="kartra_text kartra_text--light-grey kartra_text--text-medium kartra_text--text-center kartra_text--margin-bottom-medium" style="position: relative;">
              <p style="font-family: Lato;">Healthy and Yummy Immunity Boosting recipes pack to strengthen your immune system, eat healthy and keep the weight you deserve.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 colView">
        <div class="js_kartra_component_holder">
          <div data-component="image" href="javascript: void(0);">
            <picture>
              <source type="image/webp" data-srcset="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.webp" srcset="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.webp">
              <source type="image/png" data-srcset="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.png" srcset="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.png"><img class="kartra_image kartra_image--full pull-left background_changer--blur0 loaded" src="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.png" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='//d2uolguxr56s4e.cloudfront.net/img/kartrapages/placeholder.jpg';"
                alt="" style="border-color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-style: none; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; opacity: 1;" data-original="//d1aettbyeyfilo.cloudfront.net/ladynetwork/14995929_16065982577612nd-1.png" data-was-processed="true"></picture>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```